# Codeigniter calling a view

Tags: php, view, codeigniter-3

I'm new to `CodeIgniter` and i wonder what is best way to load a page without need to call  header and footer views always this way

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('something');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

for example i successfully logged in and was redirected to dashboard page .

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to have a common function/method.

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function load_view($view_name,$data=Null){
         $this->load->view('header');
         $this->load->view($view_name,$data);
         $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

Now extend all your controller with `My_Controller`(Not with CI_Controller)

From your controller call the function directly to load the view and pass `$data` array if you want to pass any data to the view.

```
$this->load_view('test_view',$data);
```

In case you have nothing to send to the view just send the view name

```
$this->load_view('test_view');
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: You are most welcome. If it helped, please upvote and accept my answer so that others can get help out of it.

Comment: i meant before i ask this question here  i used it thanks

Comment: I meant this can help others if you accept or upvote my answer. Even if your problem is solved, other developers in the community can use it.

Answer (score 0):

For that I'm using easy way like PHP:

Controller :

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function load_view(){
         $data=array();     
         $this->load->view('dashboard_view',$data);

    }
    public function get_data(){

         $data['welcome_text']="Wooh ! I've a Something...";        
         $this->load->view('dashboard_view',$data);
    }
}
```

View `dashboard_view.php`:

```
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <?php include('header.php');?>
         <h1>welcome to the dashboard </h1>   
        <?php include('footer.php');?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: 
In this you don't need to call each and everytime header and footer just change the controller methods.

Same `dashboard_view.php` for the edit function :

```
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <?php include('header.php');?>

        <?php 
        // you can use here any checking method whether it is 
        // I'll use isset() method to check  data is set or not 
        //if you don't use isset then it will give you an error when you call the load_view() method
        echo (isset($welcome_text) ? $welcome_text : '');

        ?>

        <?php include('footer.php');?>
    </body>
</html>
```